Why doesn't xv6 use a process's PID as its index in the process array?
When you are trying to create a process in xv6, you need to make it part of the global proc array and allocate a PID for it. Allocation of the PID is done by int allocpid(void) like:
int pid;
  
acquire(&pid_lock);
pid = nextpid;
nextpid = nextpid + 1;
release(&pid_lock);

return pid;

Basically having a global counter to keep track of the next available PID then assigning returning it, keeping this counter locked to prevent any race conditions.
However, this makes searching for a process with a given PID lengthy:
for(p = proc; p < &proc[NPROC]; p++) {
  if(p->pid == pid) {
    .....

What if instead of looping through the entire process array, we could have a process's PID be its index in the process array?
This will speed up looking for a process with a PID pid like:
&proc[pid]

Why isn't this used? Are there any potential flaws with this design?

xv6 pid is 32 bit integer. Can you imagine proc[1U << 31] array? What will happen if you decide to add pid randomization?

@0___________ The number of processes is still capped to NPROC. There is no need to allocate a PID outside that range. However, the need for PID randomization is a good reason not to do so. Thanks!
